# 14.04 update screwed my computer: relocation error everywhere!

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, debug

I am running Xubuntu in an old PC.

When I upgrade I got a few error messages but I didn't payed attention to them (I'm used to such things).

Now, I have lot's of bugs. Basically, from what I was able to investigate, I think (***hope***) all bugs have the same cause, thus solving *that cause* will restore my computer to normality.

Now, the cause is that I get the "relocation error" error everywhere!

- When trying to open firefox
- When trying to use apt-get

I've searched for solutions to this error and I couldn't find one that I understood or that worked for me.

Besides, I am having other malfunctions:

- "indicator plugin" from xubuntu panel crashes whenever I add it to the panel.
- same goes for "whisker menu"

(I have no idea how to investigate these bugs).

(P.S.: Thanks!! and sorry for my bad english :s !!)

P.S.2: The error I get is:

`apt: relocation error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference`

Comment: Can you confirm which version of ubuntu you upgraded to, looks like you probably may need to manually reinstall libstdc++6 but it's important to get your the right one for your distribution or you could very well make the problem much worse.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. I downloaded the libstdc++6 package but, sadly, I just couldn't install it. I tried double-clicking but nothing happened, I couldn't even decompress it. -- Finally, I gave up and ended up reinstalling xubuntu. >:(